# Запрос на множественное значение одного параметра

Tags: mysql, sql

Собственно прелюдия:
есть запрос вида:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    list_ims.name AS NAME
FROM
    measuring,
    list_ims,
    test_name,
    test_variant,
    party_ims
WHERE
    (
        measuring.id_test_variant = test_variant.id AND test_variant.id_test_name = test_name.id
    ) AND(
        measuring.id_party = party_ims.id AND party_ims.id = list_ims.id
    ) AND test_name.name = "Выходное напряжение низкого уровня UOL, В"
```

Он возвращает две строки:

```
name_1  
name_2
```

Запрос вида:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    list_ims.name AS NAME
FROM
    measuring,
    list_ims,
    test_name,
    test_variant,
    party_ims
WHERE
    (
        measuring.id_test_variant = test_variant.id AND test_variant.id_test_name = test_name.id
    ) AND(
        measuring.id_party = party_ims.id AND party_ims.id = list_ims.id
    ) AND test_name.name = "Выходное напряжение высокого уровня UOH, В"
```

Так же возвращает:

```
name_1  
name_2
```

Третий запрос с новым `test_name.name` возвращает только `name_1`

Есть ли способ через 1 запрос и перечисление всех значений `test_name.name` найти совпадение по **И**.

Пробовал так:

```
SELECT
    list_ims.name AS names_ims
FROM
    measuring,
    list_ims,
    test_name,
    test_variant,
    party_ims
WHERE
    (
        measuring.id_test_variant = test_variant.id AND test_variant.id_test_name = test_name.id
    ) AND(
        measuring.id_party = party_ims.id AND party_ims.id = list_ims.id
    ) AND test_name.name IN(
        "Выходное напряжение низкого уровня UOL, В",
        "Выходное напряжение высокого уровня UOH, В",
        'Ток потребления ICC, мА'
    )
HAVING COUNT(names_ims) = 3
```

Вернул `null`.

**Update - работающий запрос:**

```
SELECT list_ims.id, list_ims.name 
  FROM    measuring,
    list_ims,
    test_name,
    test_variant,
    party_ims,
       (select "%Выходное напряжение низкого уровня UOL, В%" as mask UNION ALL
        select "%Выходное напряжение высокого уровня UOH, В%" UNION ALL
        select "%Ток потребления ICC, мА%"
       ) src
WHERE
    (
        measuring.id_test_variant = test_variant.id AND test_variant.id_test_name = test_name.id
    ) AND(
        measuring.id_party = party_ims.id AND party_ims.id = list_ims.id
    )
    AND test_name.name LIKE src.mask
 GROUP BY list_ims.id, list_ims.name
HAVING count(distinct src.mask)=3
```

Comment: может он третьего значения не нашел. уберите having, добавьте count() в фразу select и посмотрите что он вообще возвращает. А вообще любая группировка (которую автоматически начинает использование count() или having) без "group by" это странно. если вы выводите name, то вероятно и хотите группировать по нему

Comment: @Mike По третьему значению он возвращает name_1.  Действительно, забыл group by. Но и с ним возвращается null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT list_ims.name AS NAME
FROM measuring,
     list_ims,
     test_name,
     test_variant,
     party_ims
WHERE measuring.id_test_variant = test_variant.id 
  AND test_variant.id_test_name = test_name.id
  AND measuring.id_party = party_ims.id 
  AND party_ims.id = list_ims.id
  AND test_name.name IN ( 'Выходное напряжение низкого уровня UOL, В',
                          'Выходное напряжение высокого уровня UOH, В',
                          'Ток потребления ICC, мА' )
GROUP BY list_ims.name
HAVING 3 = COUNT( /* DISTINCT */ test_name.name)
```

Comment: Снова null. Даже если убрать третий параметр в test_name.name, то ничего не изменяется. А судя по одиночным запросам - совпадение есть.

Comment: Уберите во всех своих запросах DISTINCT, получите списки, и убедитесь, что имеется первичный индекс по list_ims, присутствующий во всех трёх таблицах. PS. Чудес не бывает.

Comment: кинул рабочий вариант запроса в шапку вопроса. Таким путём все работает. Но мне кажется, что это слегка в лоб.

Comment: @Depressa Ооо... смотрите, что там у Вас с кодировками и коллациями. Где-то имеется косячок, как мне кажется...

Comment: перебил Ваш вариант вручную. И всё заработало, возможно как-то криво скопировал. Спасибо! Как я понимаю, мой вариант итоговый и Ваш - не сильно отличаются по времени отработки?

Comment: *мой вариант итоговый и Ваш - не сильно отличаются по времени отработки?* Теоретически не должны сильно отличаться. Практически всяко может быть... никогда не занимался вопросами оптимизации статически генерируемых таблиц, особенно тем, как это оптимизирует сервер. К тому же это дело сильно зависит от версии - Ваш рабочий вариант по сути ничем не отличается от варианта, когда таблица генерится не во FROM, а в WITH.